# How can I force a file download in the WordPress backend?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello everybody I have problem this code must give file to download in wordpress backend
but it give me jeson code anybody can help
here my code

```
         $oprion_name_theme =  $this->theme->options['theme_options_field'];

         $shadyssa_options  =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name like '%$oprion_name_theme%'");

         $resul = $shadyssa_options[0] ;

         $result = (array) $resul ;
         ob_start() ;
         $output =   json_encode($result) ;
         header("Content-type: application/octet-stream") ;
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='test.json'");
         header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $output ) );   
         echo $output;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `jeson`? probably it's all OK if you write `json` - without the `e`.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log. As this is wordpress, please follow the according notes in the wordpress manual/codex as well how to enable error reporting and track them.

Comment: thanks all i fix it my code does not work well because i use ajax

Comment: Please see [Simple Ajax/PHP debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485290/simple-ajax-php-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

typo here:

```
$result = (array) $resul ;
```

you want a file download? but you are outputting as json

```
 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream") ;
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='test.json'");
```

which is it that you want?